# C# Massive memory leak in GeckoFX with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, performance, html-agility-pack, geckofx

I'm writing a program to scrape lots of websites of companies (up to 100,000) for up-to-date contact information as well as some information about their field of operations in C#. Because most of the websites can't be displayed in the regular .NET webbrowser I'm using geckofx to navigate to these websites and to find the content relevant to me I select nodes with HtmlAgilityPack.

The process is always the same: If I have a URL for a company I visit the website right away, otherwise I use bing to look for a web address (Google seems to dislike being used automatically). On the website I look for a link to an imprint and links to pages that could indicate some area of activity, I navigate to these links and look for catchphrases that I specified beforehand. Everything is running synchronously, I wait for the browser to trigger its `DocumentCompleted` event everytime.

An example:

```
//I navigate to bing looking for my company's name and postal code
Variables.browser.Navigate("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + c.Name.Replace(" ", "+") + "+" + c.Zip.Replace(" ", "+"));

//I wait for the browser to finish loading. The Navigating event sets BrowserIsReady to false and the DocumentCompleted event sets it to true
do
{
    f.Application.DoEvents();
} while (!Variables.BrowserIsReady);

HtmlDocument browserDoc = new HtmlDocument();
browserDoc.LoadHtml(Variables.browser.Document.Body.OuterHtml);

//I select the relevant node in the document
HtmlNode sidebarNode = browserDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(concat(\" \", normalize-space(@class), \" \"), \" b_entityTP \")]");

if (sidebarNode != null)
{
    Variables.logger.Log("Found readable sidebar. Loading data...");
    string lookedUpName, lookedUpStreet, lookedUpCity, lookedUpZip, lookedUpPhone, lookedUpWebsite;

    HtmlNode infoNode = sidebarNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(concat(\" \", normalize-space(@class), \" \"), \" b_subModule \")]");

    HtmlNode nameNode = infoNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(concat(\" \", normalize-space(@class), \" \"), \" b_feedbackComponent \")]");
    if (nameNode != null)
    {
        string[] dataFacts = nameNode.GetAttributeValue("data-facts", "").Replace("{\"", "").Replace("\"}", "").Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (string dataFact in dataFacts)
        {
            //... abbreviated
        }
    }
    //And at the end of every call to a node object I set it back to null
    nameNode = null;
}
```

My geckofx is not allowed to write cache to memory or to load images from websites, which I set by using

```
GeckoPreferences.Default["browser.cache.memory.enabled"] = false;
GeckoPreferences.Default["permissions.default.image"] = 2;
```

before creating my GeckoWebBrowser instance.

After every scraped website I call

```
//CookieMan is used as a global variable so I don't have to recreate it every time.
private static nsICookieManager CookieMan;
//...
CookieMan = Xpcom.GetService<nsICookieManager>("@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1");
CookieMan = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsICookieManager>(CookieMan);
CookieMan.RemoveAll();
Gecko.Cache.ImageCache.ClearCache(true);
Gecko.Cache.ImageCache.ClearCache(false);
Xpcom.GetService<nsIMemory>("@mozilla.org/xpcom/memory-service;1").HeapMinimize(true);
```

to delete cookies, image cache (which I'm not sure is even created) and to minimize Xulrunners memory usage.

Nevertheless, after starting quite nicely with an approximate runtime of 2-3 seconds per record and comfortable 200-300mb memory usage, both quickly blow up to 16-17 seconds per record and over 2gb of used memory for my crawler alone after 1 hour.

I tried forcing garbage collection with `GC.Collect();` (which I know, you're not supposed to do) and even recycling the entire browser object by stopping, disposing and recreating it to try and get rid of unused junk in the memory, but to no avail. I was also trying to shut down the Xulrunner and starting it again, but `Xpcom.Shutdown()` seems to stop the entire app, so I wasn't able to do that.

I'm pretty much out of ideas at this point and would very much appreciate new hints to approaches I haven't yet taken.

Comment: Does this help at all? Perhaps the memory viewer will help you diagnose the source of the issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/memory-windows?view=vs-2019

Comment: Do you have considered about recycling the process after a number of iterations? You could have a process-controller to control the whole operation, and a process-worker that would be recyclable.

Comment: @LarryTang It seems my Visual Studio doesn't have the mentioned window. The memory usage from the diagnostic tools showed me a large reservation of memory for an Undo history in a textbox of mine, which I've since removed, but the memory usage is still uncomfortably high and the app still becomes very slow after about 400-500 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using recycled AppDomains?

```
AppDomain workerAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("WorkerAppDomain");
workerAppDomain.SetData("URL", "https://stackoverflow.com");
workerAppDomain.DoCallBack(() =>
{
    var url = (string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("URL");
    Console.WriteLine($"Scraping {url}");
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var content = webClient.DownloadString(url);
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("OUTPUT", content.Length);
});
int contentLength = (int)workerAppDomain.GetData("OUTPUT");
AppDomain.Unload(workerAppDomain);
Console.WriteLine($"ContentLength: {contentLength:#,0}");
```

Output:

> Scraping https://stackoverflow.com
>   ContentLength: 262.013

The data you pass between the main AppDomain and the worker AppDomain must be serializable.

---

**Update:** The most clean solution should be to use separate processes though. This would guarantee that the leakage can be cleaned up reliably.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Is there a way to implement this without having to redesign my entire application? I'm using a separate static Variables class to store values that almost every part of my application has to use, as well as a debug window, which logs my progess and a progress bar on my main window, none of which seem to be accessible from the AppDomain.

Comment: @C.Leimbach AppDomains are intended to be isolated, so corrupted state to one does not propagate to another. For this reason each AppDomain has its own set of static variables. Communication between two AppDomains is almost as difficult as communication between two processes. Before delving deeper on how to re-architecture your application around unloadable AppDomains, I would suggest to first verify that this approach indeed solves the problem of memory leakage. If it doesn't then you should look at making your application multi-processed instead.

Comment: A multi-processed app is what I built out of it and that seems to work for now. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. I don't know how stackoverflow works in this regard. Should I accept your answer as the right one, even if I didn't end up using AppDomains to solve the problem?

Comment: @C.Leimbach I updated my answer to include a reference to multi-processing as a solution. 